# Umount /dev/sda1 accidentally and now unable to open ubuntu in vmware

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, data-recovery, umount

I ran out of memory in ubuntu 14.04 installed on VMWare Player. So i was trying to delete some file but accidentally used.

```
    sudo umount -l /
```

this command made all the partitions of same configuration as that of /dev/sda1. Niether i am able to login nor able to access tty1.
I have tried a alot of things but unable to reach a solution.

Please help me in opening ubuntu back or atleast recover my data as it contains my research of 1 year and other important projects.

Comment: Can you put up here, the output `lsblk` command?

Comment: There is no place to put any command as i am not able to login and access tty1 state. In short i am stuck but was hoping for a solution to recover my data somehow.